# Continue numeric series in data.frame column with sequential numbers

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], B = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA))
df
   A  B
1  a  1
2  b  1
3  c  2
4  d  2
5  e  3
6  f  4
7  g  5
8  h NA
9  i NA
10 j NA
```

In the B column, I would like to replace the NAs and continue the numeric series with the next numbers, to obtain a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
   A  B
1  a  1
2  b  1
3  c  2
4  d  2
5  e  3
6  f  4
7  g  5
8  h  6
9  i  7
10 j  8
```

It sounds simple enough, but I haven't figured out a way to do it.

Any ideas/pointers welcome, and a tidyverse solution would be preferable - thanks!

Comment: Did you try using for or while loops?

Comment: What happens when you have input like `1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA, 10, 11`  and what happens when you have `NA , NA, 1, 2, 3, NA, 7, NA, NA, 10` ? A better example covering such edge cases would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a one-liner solution based on `zoo`'s function `na.locf0` ("after `NA`, last observation carried forward"):

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(B = ifelse(is.na(B), na.locf0(B) + cumsum(is.na(B)), B))
   A B
1  A 1
2  B 1
3  C 2
4  D 2
5  E 3
6  F 4
7  G 5
8  H 6
9  I 7
10 J 8
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:10], 
                 B = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way, but it only works if the vector's `NA` values are all at the end of it.

```
df$B <- ifelse(is.na(df$B), max(df$B, na.rm = TRUE) + cumsum(is.na(df$B)), df$B)

df
#   A B
#1  a 1
#2  b 1
#3  c 2
#4  d 2
#5  e 3
#6  f 4
#7  g 5
#8  h 6
#9  i 7
#10 j 8
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  B = replace(B, is.na(B), max(B, na.rm = TRUE) + seq(sum(is.na(B))))
```

gives

```
   A B
1  a 1
2  b 1
3  c 2
4  d 2
5  e 3
6  f 4
7  g 5
8  h 6
9  i 7
10 j 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution in base R with for loop:

```
n = max(df$B[is.na(df$B) == FALSE])
for (i in 1:length(df$B[is.na(df$B) == TRUE])){
  n = n+1
  df$B[is.na(df$B) == TRUE][1] = n
}
```

Output:

```
   A B
1  a 1
2  b 1
3  c 2
4  d 2
5  e 3
6  f 4
7  g 5
8  h 6
9  i 7
10 j 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very satisfied with this approach, but you could use

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(is.na(B))) %>% 
  fill(B, .direction = "down") %>% 
  mutate(B = B + grp, .keep = "unused")
```

which returns

```r
   A B
1  a 1
2  b 1
3  c 2
4  d 2
5  e 3
6  f 4
7  g 5
8  h 6
9  i 7
10 j 8
```